# image in a list not being displayed correctly(as if in table), how to do that

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code something like this :

```
<ul>
   <li>some text <img src="path" style="height:15px;width:25px;" /></li>
   <li>some text <img src="path" style="height:15px;width:25px;" /></li>
   <li>some text <img src="path" style="height:15px;width:25px;" /></li>
</ul>
```

What i want is , the "some text" and img should come neatly, as if they are 2 cols in a table . Also, if text is small like "ab" , then the image should not change its position , i mean, shouldnt come near, it should be always at far distance like some 80px after "some text" . And,if text length is more than 80, img should lie after text only .  Will provide more information if necessary .
Thanks

Comment: Try positioning the img "absolutely" within the li element

Comment: Suggested new title: Can someone code this for me?

Comment: You should try at least to add some style before asking others to do, umm?

Comment: @Vishal plz dont think i am working on that simple code, my code is different and complex,so posted in a simple way .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li><span style="min-width:80px; display: inline-block;">some text</span>
<img src="path" style="height:15px;width:25px; float:left;" /></li>
```

This will works...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by adding a couple of span tags inside the list items and some CSS as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">

li {
    clear: left;
}

li span {
    display:block;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
}

li img {
    float: left;
}
​
</style>

<ul>
    <li><span>some text</span><img src="path" style="height:15px;width:25px;" /></li>
    <li><span>some text bla bla bla</span><img src="path" style="height:15px;width:25px;" /></li>
    <li><span>some text</span><img src="path" style="height:15px;width:25px;" /></li>
</ul>​
```

You can check out the result of this here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/magnusohlin/xhLmx/